# Ограничить TextBox вводом чисел до сотой части WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь понять, как можно ограничить TextBox вводом не более двух чисел после точки?

Допусти, пользователь ввёл число 10.234 программа сохранила только 10.23 обрезав оставшуюся часть

я сделал так:

```
        int l,n;
        n = txbPrice.Text.IndexOf(".");

        if (n > 0 && txbPrice.Text.Length > n + 3)
        {
            txbPrice.Text = txbPrice.Text.Substring(0, n + 3);
            l = txbPrice.Text.Length;
        }
```

в событие TextChanged

теперь задача такая, чтобы программа дописывала, допусти пользователь ввел 12 и программа автоматически дописала 12.00 или если ввели 12.2 программа дописала до 12.20, как добиться этого?

Comment: Привяжите к double свойству и округляйте в сеттере.

Comment: @aepot, я кое-что вписал в событие TextChanged, теперь остался другой вопрос, чтобы программа дописывала, допусти пользователь ввел 12 и программа автоматически дописала 12.00 или если ввели 12.2 программа дописала до 12.20, как добиться этого?

Comment: Не, это все костыли. Я же вам сказал, привяжите к double и округляйте в сеттере. Чтобы дописывались нули достаточно в привязке указать `StringFormat=F2`. Никаких обработчиков событий не требуется.

Comment: @aepot, чтоб дописывались нули сделал, честно говоря как привязать к Double и указать то что в сеттере, я не знаю, можете показать?

Comment: @aepot, насчет дописывания, я сделал так  Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={}{0:0.00}

Comment: `set => _number = Math.Round(value, 2);`

Comment: @aepot, такая проблема, я сделал чтобы авто дописывалось окончание сотая часть, но проблема в том, что на textbox она отображена, как нужно, но в базу сохраняется так, как ввел пользователь, допусти я ввожу 10, она авто дописала 10.00, но в базе зафиксировала как 10 без .00

Comment: В базе какого типа поле? Если число, то 10 и 10.00 - это одно и то же (вдруг вы не в курсе).

Comment: @aepot, в базе данных deciaml(16,2)

Comment: Ну, и что вы тогда хотели. 10 и 10.00 - одно и то же число. Кстати, если это деньги, то лучше конечно использовать decimal, а не double.

Comment: @aepot, так я decimal и использовал

Comment: так, всё, вопрос решил

Answer (score 0):

```
    int l,n;
    n = txbPrice.Text.IndexOf(".");

    if (n > 0 && txbPrice.Text.Length > n + 3)
    {
        txbPrice.Text = txbPrice.Text.Substring(0, n + 3);
        l = txbPrice.Text.Length;
    }
```

и в xaml

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Цена" Binding="{Binding Amount, StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}"/>
```

Comment: `IndexOf(".")` в русском языке разделитель запятая, а не точка. Надеюсь, вы уверены в том, что делаете. Я бы прописал `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` и не занимался бы ерундятиной с обработчиками.

Comment: Там правда есть [нюанс](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30318135/12888024) с UpdateSourceTrigger, но это не проблема в целом.